# Javascript date/string manipulation

Tags: javascript

I receive a date from server like `2017-08-12T00:00:00+00:00`. I need to display it in dd/mm/yyyy format.

How should I manipulate it? Is moment required or is it simple string processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let getFormat = (dateString) => {
   let date = new Date(dateString);
   return date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth() + 1)+"/"+date.getFullYear();
}
getFormat("2017-08-12T00:00:00+00:00");
```

If you want to prepend 0 then use:

```
let getFormat = (dateString) => {
   let date = new Date(dateString);
   let day = date.getDate() < 10 ? "0"+date.getDate() : date.getDate();
   let month = (date.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? "0"+(date.getMonth() + 1) : (date.getMonth() + 1);

   return day+"/"+month+"/"+date.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this will not add 0 in front of single digit days/months, so you can get something like d/m/yyyy

Comment: Okay let me try